# Eclipse ignoring source when deploying webapp

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, javabeans

I'm running eclipse with tomcat 5.5. For some unknown reason from one day to the other eclipse stoped compiling my beans and java files that are in the source folder.

If I go to the work directory, I find all the JSP compiled, the folders of the packadges i have, but no classes compiled inside of them. Neither eclipse, nor tomcat give errors. (Except when i try to access the non existing classes)

Anyone has any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

/fmsf

Answer (score 2):

You might have "Build automatically" disabled. You can find it in the Project menu.

Comment: it's enabeled, the JSP are being compiled, it's just the java files, beans and such that are being ignored

Comment: Maybe the sources are no longer part of the build path?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with such a scenario once. In addition it did not detect the local changes w.r.t the code repository. Honestly I don't know the reason but use of a new eclipse installation (Extraction) on same workspace resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

One of the files came out of SVN without read access. Eclipse blocked reading it and wouldn't compile.

+1 to all tks